# Order between Action filter attributes and controller inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have 2 abstract api controllers that pretty much look like this:

```
[BaseActionFilter]
public abstract class ApiBaseController : ApiController
{
}

[StackActionFilter]
public abstract class StackApiBaseController : ApiBaseController 
{
}
```

Now I'm using 2 action filters that override the `OnActionExecuting` method and do some business logic.

Now when I use controllers who inherit from `ApiBaseController`, the `BaseActionFilter` works just fine.

When I use controllers who inherit from `StackApiBaseController`, I have a problem.

**My problem** is that `StackActionFilter` depends on the result of the `BaseActionFilter`, and in my case runs **before** the `BaseActionFilter` runs(*I thought that the "fathers" run first*).

Is there any way I can put some order here? I want the `BaseActionFilter` to run before the `StackActionFilter` when I use controllers that inherit `StackApiBaseController`.

Comment: Are these custom filters? If so, you should set the `Order` property of the filters to control what order they're executed in.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, these are ActionFilterAttributes. I don't have any order property inside them.

Comment: Yes, I realise these are `ActionFilterAttribute`s. What I was asking was whether you had made these yourself by inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` (and therefore have access to protected accessors), or if these are builtin classes or from some library.

Comment: yes, they are inherited and I override the 'OnActionExecuting' method in both cases.

Comment: Okay, so then in the constructor of both attribute classes, set the protected `Order` property to different values, according to the order in which you need them to execute.

Comment: I tried that before and don't have any protected var called order..I'm talking about the webapi filters that sit in this namespace: 'System.Web.Http.Filters'.
I know the 'System.Web.Mvc' filters have the order property, but this isn't the case.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry about the confusion. In that case, what you need to do is implement an `IFilterProvider` which will determine the order in which your attributes get applied. Here's a tutorial: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/control-the-execution-order-of-your-filters-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: @Asad this looks interesting but has a big overhead for just "ordering" two attributes. There must be a better solution. If I wont get one, I'll try to implement this one. Thanks for you time & help.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to make the *StackActionFilterAttribute* inherit from the *BaseactionFilterAttribute* and apply only the *StackActionFilterAttribute* to the *StackApiBaseController*.

You can then control the order by where you put the base.OnActionExecuting call in *StackApiActionFilterAttribute*.

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //HERE
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        //OR HERE
```

It's not ideal because you need to take the *BaseactionFilterAttribute* off the *ApiBaseController* and therefore lose control of that generic capability being enforced on any controller that inherits directly from *ApiBaseController* but it does provide a solution to the question as stated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add the BaseActionFilter to the StackApiController, they will execute in the order they are applied.

Comment: I know that it will work, but it doesn't seem right to me to duplicate the filters when I use inheritance to "gain" the fathers features.

Comment: you are still gaining the base classes filter right? BaseActionFilter will still be called just not in the order you like.

Comment: I understand what you are try to accomplish here, but the BaseActionFilter will be on both controllers and this doesn't seem like the right approach here..